# JQuery, calculating 2 prices, show total

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to calculate the total price according to 2 selected radio buttons. Here is what I have:

Radio buttons

html input class is fare

```
<td class='v2'><input type='radio' name='fare' value='STANDARD' id='rbt2'>625,06</td>
<td class='v2'><input type='radio' name='fare2' value='STANDARD' id='rbt9'>884,34</td>

$(document).ready(function(){
           $("#rbt, #rbt2, #rbt3, #rbt4, #rbt5, #rbt6, #rbt7").click(function(){
                $("#fare").html($(this).closest("td").text());
           });
       });

       $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#rbt8, #rbt9, #rbt10, #rbt11, #rbt12, #rbt13, #rbt14").click(function(){
                 $("#fare2").html($(this).closest("td").text()); 
           });
       });
```

Jquery calculator

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //iterate through each radio and add keyup
    //handler to trigger sum event
    $(".fare").each(function() {

        $(this).keyup(function(){
            calculateTotal();
        });
    });

});

function calculateTotal() {

    var total = 0;
    //iterate through each radio and add the values
    $(".fare").each(function() {

        //add only if the value is number
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!==0) {
            total += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
    //.toFixed() method will roundoff the final sum to 2 decimal places
    $("#total").html(total.toFixed(2));
}
```

html output

```
<tr>
   <td class="sc2" id="fare"></td>
   <td>+</td>
   <td class="sc2" id="fare2"></td>
   <td>=</td>
   <td><span class="total">0</span></td>
 </tr>
```

The total is not being shown. Help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can i see you HTML for your radio buttons? Also when exactly do you want to calculate the total? What event?

Comment: can you post enough HTML to clarify?

Comment: Just updated, see above.

Comment: Event should happen when the second radio has been clicked.

Comment: As an aside, note that although it will work to have multiple document ready handlers you don't need to do it that way, not for code in the same source file. Just put both of your `.click()` calls inside the same document ready handler.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to post the complete html of the radio. See above.

Comment: Calculation should be based on the values, i.e. 625,06 and the value of the second radio(onclick) in the td.

Comment: Those are not numbers... replace the commas with decimal points, and if you need to display them using commas, use a formatter when displaying the value.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    $(".fare").keyup(function(){
        calculateTotal(); <--- you don't need to use each() here.
    });

});

function calculateTotal() {
    ...
    $("#total").html(total.toFixed(2));
}
```

html output

```
<tr>
   ...
   <td><span id="total">0</span></td> <---- change 'class' to 'id'
 </tr>
```

Note the changes.

Comment: "STANDARD" is not a number, so of course it's not going to update.